# How do I split regex this string

Tags: java, regex

Im trying to understand how would regex work in this case of split/Pattern.compile

This is the entire string: `"#[flowVars['variable_name']]"`

The string i need to extract would be `"variable_name"`

How can i achieve this with a regex? or even with a longer name instead of `"flowVars"` could be something else.

EDITED:

Constructed a method using split and iterating twice to find all the matches / variables between quotes, just in case if someone wants to re-use it or modify it

```
private static List<String> rebuildURLWithComplexValues(String url) {

    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();;

    if(url != null && url.length() > 0) {
        if(url.contains("flowVars")) {              
            String[] firstSplit = url.split("\\[");
            for (int i = 0; i < firstSplit.length; i++) {
                if(firstSplit[i].contains("'")) {
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(firstSplit[i], "\'");                      
                    String tokencitu = st.nextToken();
                    tokens.add(tokencitu);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

Thanks everyone :D

Comment: Please put some effort in learning. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Like all regex questions, you must know the valid strings in order to decide what you want to parse.  Is `"#[flowVars['a']['b']]"` a valid string?  what would you want parsed out? What syntax is it in what context?  These are needed for regex to not give you bad data.

Comment: im kinda new with regex, i know only the basics like [a-Z] and stuff, but don't know when i need to add other characters, or how to make the entire regex. Tried doing things like "\\#[flowVars" but says its wrong

Comment: @DMoses the exact string is that one, that's why i tried capturing the entire thing like "\\#[flowVars['" but throws an exception of "Unclosed character class"

Comment: If it's that exact string, the answer is `variable_name`.  If it is similar, what can change and how?  is `variable_name` a alphanumeric?  can it include escapesequences with `'` or `]`?

Comment: ohhh i see @DMoses i mean, the variable_name is a random name i placed, but can be anything... but the restrictions are alpha characters with "-" or "_", and allow capslock too [a-A] for example, the escape sequence would be the single ' around the variable name

Comment: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) and [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) would be nice places to start.

Comment: Here is a starting point if you want.  You need to change the inside of () to handle all the values, it should work on the 4 test cases:  http://jsfiddle.net/L2Yxq/

Comment: @DMoses the fiddle doesn't open :(

Comment: @msqar Sorry, I updated it http://jsfiddle.net/L2Yxq/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, more information is required, but the simplest way just based on your sample is to take everything between single quotes:

```
String input = "#[flowVars['variable_name']]";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll(".*'(.*)'.*", "$1"));
```

This translates to: anything (`.*`), followed by single quote (`'`), followed by a captured block of anything (`(.*)`) followed by single quote, followed by anything, take that and replace it with the captured block.

If you want to tinker with it, try:

http://regexr.com?35kof

For instance, you can use more than one capture block, you just reference them in order (`$1` for the first captured block, `$2` for the second, etc.):

```
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(.*)'(.*)'(.*)", "$2, $1, $3"));
```

If you have multiple variables to pick out, like:

```
String input = "#[flowVars['variable_name1']]#[flowVars['variable_name2']]";
```

You can use Java's `Pattern` and `Matcher` with the following regex:

```
String regex = "(?<=#\[flowVars\[')[^']*";
```

Which translates to: Anything that starts with "#[flowVars['" but doesn't include that in the match `(?<=#\[flowVars\[')`, followed by however many non-quotes `[^']` (which gives you everything up to the first quote it sees).

Just loop through the matcher's groups from there, no need for nested looping.

Comment: nice this one works excellent. Is there any way to capture more than 1 string in a string? and separate them by a comma or something ?

Comment: Sure, just add more capture blocks to the pattern.  I added an example of this.

Comment: I see, wouldn't be nicer to use a "split" method to get all the matches into an array? imagine i could have multiple "#[flowVars['variable_name']]" in the string, is there any regex for the split to catch this? tried yours in a split but didn't work, only with replaceAll. Btw thanks for the help!

Comment: Made my way using splits and iterating twice, thanks anyway for all your help and to others.

Comment: No problem, added a regex for only iterating once, for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String str = "#[flowVars['variable_name']]";
String repl = str.replaceAll("^#\\[[^\\[]*\\['([^']+).*$", "$1");
```

OR even simpler:

```
String repl = str..replaceAll("^#[^']*'([^']+).*$", "$1");
// repl = variable_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing you're looking for is not splitting via a regex, but rather getting matches from a regex. This regex should work for your purposes:

```
"#\[[A-Za-z]+\['([A-Za-z_]+)']]"
```

The parenthesis around [A-Za-z] is something called a capture. It basically takes whatever's in the parenthesis and allows you to access it afterwards. If you don't understand the regex itself, you can look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). If you do, I explain the capture piece below.

The capture groups piece works like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#\[[A-Za-z]+\['([A-Za-z_]+)']]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("#[flowVars['variable_name']]");
```

Then from there, you can get the capture group by calling

```
string output = m.group(1);
```

The capture groups start at index 1 because the 0th index contains the entire matched string.

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: how could i use that regex with split method ? thanks in advance

Comment: The way the split method works, is it takes anything that matches the regex, and makes that a location where the string splits. In your situation, the problem with using the split method, is it will remove some of the input string. (From your post, it seems like that's not what you want. If that is what you want then let me know!) for example if you split the string "hi there!" by the space character, you get ["hi", "there"], and loose the space. That's the reason I suggested using Pattern.compile(). If you still want an example using split, can you clarify what you want to be returned?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 String str="#[flowVars['variable_name']]";
  Pattern p=Pattern.compile("\\['.*?']");
  Matcher m=p.matcher(str);
    if(m.find()){              
        System.out.println(m.group(0).replaceAll("\\['","").replaceAll("\\']",""));
    }
```